CI/CD Github Action Workflow is failing to ssh to my aws ec2 instance
CI/CD Github Action Workflow is failing to ssh/connect to my aws ec2 instance
So I have an ec2 instance and I connected it to a domain name, I wanted to build A CI/CD pipeline for my Django project So the Github workflow ssh's into my instance and pulls code whenever there is a change in my main branch in the Github Repository, I followed this thenewboston tutorial and I get an error message whenever it reaches Run deploy step in the workflow,here is the debug error from the Run deploy step:
 ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Run deploy'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Run deploy
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Loading env
Run ssh target "cd my_repo/ && docker-compose down && git pull && docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate"
##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /home/runner/work/_temp/a5810d79-db8d-4e78-9f23-433261499e8f.sh
Removing network myreponame_default
Network myreponame_default not found.
***@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
##[debug]Finishing: Run deploy

here is the image of the same above error
The setup is like this:

Repository is private

I created an ssh rsa key in my local computer with the command ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f Desktop/Deployment/Github

Printed out the private key with the command type Desktop\Deployment\Github and copied it to my Repository Secrets in my repository settings with the name SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

Printed out the public key Github.pub and copied it to my ec2 instance into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Created 2 more Repository Secrets SSH_HOST AND SSH_USER where I put the domain name in SSH_HOST and the user in SSH_USER So when the workflow connects it do: SSH_USER@SSH_HOST


the workflow file (main.yml):
name: Continuous Integration

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

concurrency:
  group: main
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  quality-assurance:
    name: Quality Assurance
    uses: ./.github/workflows/pr.yml

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: quality-assurance
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Configure SSH
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          SSH_HOST: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          SSH_USER: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
          echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/github
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/github
          cat >>~/.ssh/config <<END
          Host target
            HostName $SSH_HOST
            User $SSH_USER
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
            LogLevel ERROR
            StrictHostKeyChecking no
          END
      - name: Run deploy
        run: |
          ssh target "cd my_repo/ && docker-compose down && git pull && docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d --force-recreate"

Here is the git configuration file:
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=ssh://github.com/myname/myrepo.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main

I have no Idea why the error occurs when it tries to connect, I tried changing the Git config, changed ssh:// to just git@github.com:user/repo but the same error appears , the SSH_HOST to the IP but that didn't work either, I always connect just fine to the instance manually via ssh with this command ssh -i key.pem user@domain.com, I doubt the error is inside the main.yml file and it probably is inside the Git configuration (I guess?)
Lastly, I apologize for my bad English and sorry if the question is wrongly constructed as this is my first question ever on Stackoverflow

Curious, but why did you put StrictHostKeyChecking no in that config file?

Also, your output suggests that the connection to target works fine, but that target is unable to authenticate to GitHub. Does target have an SSH keypair? Is the public key associated with the repo(s) in question, or with an account that has access to those?

This worked for me:

First, make sure your EC2 instance has a security group that allows 22 connections
Run it locally to make sure the ansible is working from your machine
Then, that was how I managed to run deploy using ansible playbook on an EC2 instance:
Add the pair_key.pem (that AWS provided and make you access you instance) into the github actions as a secret, name it as PRIVATE_KEY.

      - name: Deploy to AWS
        shell: bash
        env:
          PRIVATE_KEY : ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          touch ~/.ssh/private.key
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private.key
          echo -e "$PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/private.key
          cd devops/ansible/
          eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
          ssh-add ~/.ssh/private.key
          ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts/dev --tags backend --private-key ~/.ssh/private.key


